# Just switched to ubuntu and I can't install stuff D:

Tags: software-installation

I tried installing VSC through the website and when I downloaded the .deb option the Ubuntu software app would open and It would say failed to install file not supported so I just downloaded it directly from the  app now I'm getting the same problem with Nordvpn D: and it's not in the app so i'm scared

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the default Ubuntu Software application (also known as Snap Store) is not very good for installing **offline** `.deb` files. You have two options:

1 ) Install from the terminal. Open terminal and use the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagefile.deb
```

It can print a message that it cannot install the package due to missing dependencies. In that case, you need to download all required packages listed in the output and install them first. Therefore I recommend method 2:

2 ) First install the GDebi tool (it is the "original" GUI tool for installing the `.deb` packages) by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then, right click on the `.deb` file you want to install and select to open it with GDebi. GDebi will download and install all dependencies (if possible, ie. if they are available in Ubuntu repositories; otherwise you still need to find them and install yourself) and then install the `.deb` file.

Comment: Third option which I like more: `sudo apt install ./packagefile.deb` while in the directory that the downloaded .deb is in.  Will resolve the dependencies automatically (and is superior to method 1 you specified.  You can use `apt-get` but still

Comment: @ThomasWard a good option as well, but I prefer GDebi anyway :)

Comment: perhaps, but my goal was to give you an alternative to `dpkg -i` and then having to do `apt install -f` or similar.  And so you can provide a more complete answer ;)

Comment: you guys are the best ily <3